# Qual a forma correta de interromper uma thread no Delphi

Tags: android, delphi, thread

Estou criando uma thread com as informações e estrutura básicas, conforme indicado abaixo. Aparentemente está tudo funcionando bem, porém observei que ao executar o `Terminate`, a thread não passa pelo `Destroy`. Colocando um breakpoint do `Destroy` observei que a thread só vai finalizar efetivamente quando a aplicação principal finalizar também. 
Estou testando no Android e minha versão do Delphi é a 10.2.

**THREAD BÁSICA**

```
// MyThread "TPoolingThread"
constructor TPoolingThread.Create;
begin
   inherited Create(True); // Inicialização suspensa

   // Inicializa algumas coisas
end;

destructor TPoolingThread.Destroy;
begin
   inherited Destroy;
end;

procedure TPoolingThread.Execute;
begin
   try
      while (not Terminated) do begin
         sleep(100);
         // faz algumas coisas
      end;
   finally
      if not Terminated then
         Terminate;
   end;
end;
```

**EXECUTANDO A THREAD**

```
// Na aplicação principal.... 

   //////////////////////////////////////////
   // Crio e inicializo a thread no BOTÃO 1
   MyThread := TPoolingThread.Create;
   MyThread.Start;

   //////////////////////////////////////////
   // Interrompo a thread no BOTÃO 2
   MyThread.Terminate;
```

Comment: Experimente setar a propriedade `FreeOnTerminate` para `True`. dessa forma quando o processo que ela executa terminar ela se alto destruirá.

Comment: Sim, verifiquei que ao colocar o `FreeOnTerminate = True` o `Destroy` é executado, mas agora o `Finally` é ignorado (ocorre apenas no Android). Achei isso um comportamento estranho. Aí entra naquelas questões que a gente não sabe que decisão tomar em relação a qual a forma correta de fazer. Minha preocupação é que em algum momento o programa comece a ter comportamentos estranhos por conta de uma simples liberação incorreta de thread.

Comment: Se o `destroy` for executado, é correto o `finaly` ser ignorado, uma vez que o objeto não existe mais! Muito provável que o funcionamento vai ocorrer corretamente.

Comment: Eu vou observar para ver como se comporta. Obrigado.